# Bootstrap nav bar items not aligning to right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the two buttons in the div to align right. But currently, it goes to the middle while I am trying to align to the right.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-light navigation-clean">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1"><a class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" role="button" href="#">Sign Up</a></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-2"><a class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" role="button" href="#">Sign Up</a></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: where is your css part?

Comment: @Aahad i believe they are all from bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand bg-light navigation-clean">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
      <a class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" role="button" href="#">Sign Up</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary ml-2" role="button" href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi this is great thank you so much. Sorry, do you know how to make this nav bar transparent? I tried changing it to bg-transparent but It is not working